# Storing Address of a character to an Integer Pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

As we know that the task of a pointer (In C++) is to store an address. The size of address depends on the computer architecture .
For this example let us assume that we have a 32-bit machine and the size of address is 4-Byte  . Now if we create an Integer pointer

```
int x=20;
int * ptr;
ptr = &x;    //  This is fine the address of x is of 4-Bytes
```

Similarly if we have a character c

```
char c='a';
ptr = &c;      // This puts an error although address size of &c is still 4-Byte.
```

The task of the pointer is to store an address then why ptr do not store the address of a character. Although the address for both the integer and a character is of 4-Bytes.There is no datatype of address then should it not save the address in ptr (pointer) ?

Comment: Pointers have data types. The pointer contains the address *of an object* and the pointer type includes the type information about that object. A pointer isn't just a number, conceptually. Compilers can implement pointers as numbers because the compiler also keeps track of the type while it is compiling the program, but that information is no longer needed once compilation is finished (aka. C is statically-typed0.

Comment: Since you mention you understand the point better now, don't forget to accept one of your answers by clicking the green checkmark next to it! This will give both you and the person whose answer you accept a few reputation points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not that the pointer variable is the wrong size. The issue is one of type safety. You are declaring that the pointer variable contains the address of an `int`. Which means that when you try to pass the address of a `char`, the compiler complains. It says, "you promised to give me the address of an int, but that is the address of a char".

The compiler is not trying to protect you against problems with **storing** the address. As you note, there are none. The problem that the compiler is protecting you from is that which arises when you **de-reference** the address.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It really helped me. I got the right point.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just think what would happen when you try to dereference the pointer.  If

```
int * ptr;
char c='a';
ptr = &c;
```

worked, what would

```
int d = *ptr;
```

put in `d`?  In fact, since an `int` is 4 bytes but a `char` is only 1, reading from `d` would produce garbage and writing to it would contaminate the subsequent 3 bytes.

Comment: Yes exactly . I got it. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you define ptr in your second case as

```
char *ptr;
```

then that will compile. The pointer is still, as you said, 4 bytes on a 32-bit architecture. The reason for writing char * is just to clarify that your pointer is pointing to a char type.  This makes your code less buggy, it makes it possible to easily point to structure/class members etc.

In theory you could of course cast your char-pointer to an int-pointer, they're both pointers. But this would not be correct as the data you're pointing to is not an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Basically to ensure some kind of [type safety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety), even if `void*` always ruins the party. As [you can see](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/128fad29c2b855d7) in this little example, a pointer to `void` does what you are looking for:

```
int main() {
    int x = 0;
    char y = 'a';
    void* ptr = &x;
    ptr = &y;
}
```

But it's a C-ism, and you should probably use either `boost::any` or `boost::variant` to express a variable that can be of different types.

Comment: Can You please explain a little bit more. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do that, try type casting... But I can bet that you are going to get into a lots of trouble...

```
ptr = (int *)&c;
```

Comment: I don't have to do this . I was just wondering that why I can't store the address as there is no data type of an address. I just wanted to know that why languages don't allow this.Thanks

Comment: Than I guess that Johan gives the right answer for you

Answer (score 0):

**Because *types* exist.**

If this were allowed:

```
char x   = '!';
int* ptr = &x;
```

then the type of the expression `*ptr` would be `int`, which is wrong because the pointer is pointing to a `char`, not an `int`.

Comment: No idea what the downvote was about. Your answer looks good to me... +1 to undo the damage.

Answer (score 0):

```
char c='a';
int * ptr;
ptr = &c;
printf("%d",*ptr);
```

The above gives you garbage value for *ptr in the output of print because we are declaring that the pointer variable contains the address of an int. Which means that when you try to pass the address of a char then the compiler says that the pointer is integer type so we have to pass integer address only but we are passing the address of a char which is 1 byte but integer pointer points to 4 bytes address.